# JavaScript - How to call different functions based on index while looping through an array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, loops

I want to create a loop of Javascript array, when the index of array 0, a scope function f0 will be executed. Similarly when index is f1, a scope function f1 will be executed. In this it will continue for all indices of the array. For every index ( while looping) a specific function will be executed.

```
var myArray = ["0","1","2","3","4","5"];

var len = myArray.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
if(index is 0){function0() code}
if(index is 1){function1() code}
................
}
```

**The functions will be angular scope function like  $scope.f1 = function(){}**

Comment: Wheres the problem/code??

Comment: This is a very simple programming problem, not an AngularJS specific problem.  You should spend some time working through basic tutorials on JavaScript syntax and functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.f0 = function () {console.log('func f0 has been called')};
  $scope.f1 = function () {console.log('func f1 has been called')};
  
  var myArray = ["0","1"];

  // using angular foreach
  angular.forEach(myArray, function (item, index) {
    $scope['f' + index]();
  });

  // using native foreach
  myArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
    $scope['f' + index]();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you please post a code snippet like the ibrahim mahrir did for me

Comment: what is 'f' in your code? Can you please make a snippet

Comment: @msm0204 A whole working angular snippett will be hard here. Read about [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). `someObject["text" + 55]` is the same as `someObject.text55`. So if `index` is `0` then  `$scope.f0` will be called because `$scope['f' + index]()` is the same as `$scope.f0()`, ... and so on

Comment: @msm0204 I have created the snippet for you

Comment: @bijin-ab instead of f0,f1 & so on , can functions named like $scope.showHome , $scope.showAbout ,$scope.showContacts be called ?

Comment: @bijin-ab can we use traditional for loop in this purpose ?

Comment: Your array should have the function names as `var myArray = ["Home", "About"];` and invoke using 'item' arg of foreach callback instead of index. `$scope['show' + item]();`

Comment: @msm0204 To do it in traditional for loop, `var myArray = ["Home", "About"];` `for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { $scope['show' + myArray[i]](); };`

Comment: @msm0204 You should spend some time on the basics of javascript